# &bullet; doesn't work in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-entities

Is that not an acceptable HTML code to use when designing pages?  It renders correctly in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, etc... but IE literally outputs `& bullet;`

but even when I type the HTML code in this text box it gives me a bullet!  •

Is this method deprecated?  Should I resort to the ASCII # or something?

Many thanks SO

Comment: have you tried `&bull;`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using `&bull;` for •.